# Mantener variable de un get

Tags: php

Tengo un php que obtiene una variable por url que tiene un include que hace una consulta en la base de datos pero al ir y regresar de ese archivo se pierde el valor de $ID del inicio.

Este es el primer archivo

```php
<?php
  include('db.php');

  $ID=$_GET['ID'];
  <h1>Busqueda</h1>
  <form action="material_list.php" method="post">
    <select name="ID_Clasificacion">
      <option value="">Todos</option>
<?php
  $sql1="SELECT *  FROM Clasificacion";
  $query1=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1);
  while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row1['ID'].'">'.$row1['Clasificacion'].'</option>';
  }
?>
    </select>
    <select name="ID_Familia">
      <option value="">Todos</option>
<?php
  include('db.php');

  $sql="SELECT *  FROM Familia";
  $query=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['Familia']." ".$row['Subfamilia'].'</option>';
  }
?>
    </select>
    <select name="Estado">
      <option value="">Todos</option>
      <option value="Prestamo">Prestamo</option>
      <option value="En Estante">En Estante</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="ID_Taller" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $ID_Taller ?>">
    <button type="submit">Filtrar</button>
  </form>
  <h1>Materiales Disponibles:</h1>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Familia</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
  include './php/consulta_material_practica.php';

  while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    $Familia=$row1['ID_Familia'];
    $Taller=$row1['ID_Taller'];
    $Clasificacion=$row1['ID_Clasificacion'];
    $Ubicacion=$row1['ID_Ubicacion'];

    $sql2="SELECT *  FROM Familia Where ID='$Familia' ";
    $query2=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql2);
    $row2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2);

    $sql4="SELECT *  FROM Clasificacion Where ID='$Clasificacion' ";
    $query4=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql4);
    $row4=mysqli_fetch_array($query4);

    $sql5="SELECT *  FROM Ubicacion Where ID='$Ubicacion' ";
    $query5=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql5);
    $row5=mysqli_fetch_array($query5);
?>
    <tr>
      <th><?php  echo $row1['ID']?></th>
      <th><?php  echo $row1['Nombre']?></th>
      <th><?php  echo $row2['Familia']." ".$row2['Subfamilia']?></th>
      <th><a href="php/insertar_material_mae.php?ID_Material=<?php
        echo $row1['ID'] ?>&ID_Practica=<?php
        echo $row['ID'] ?>">Agregar</a></th>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Este es el include (el segundo archivo) y es un archivo para consulta nada más, no sobrescribo el valor anterior del get, y de este regresa al anterior (al primer archivo) con la consulta mostrándolo en la tabla.

```php
<?php
  include 'db.php';

  if(!isset($_POST['ID_Taller'])){
    $_POST['ID_Taller']="";
    $ID_Taller=$_POST['ID_Taller'];
  }

  if(!isset($_POST['Estado'])){
    $_POST['Estado']="";
    $Estado=$_POST['Estado'];
  }

  if(!isset($_POST['ID_Familia'])){
    $_POST['ID_Familia']="";
    $ID_Familia=$_POST['ID_Familia'];
  }

  if(!isset($_POST['ID_Clasificacion'])){
    $_POST['ID_Clasificacion']="";
    $ID_Clasificacion=$_POST['ID_Clasificacion'];
  }

  $ID_Taller=$_POST['ID_Taller'];
  $ID_Clasificacion=$_POST['ID_Clasificacion'];
  $ID_Familia=$_POST['ID_Familia'];
  $Estado=$_POST['Estado'];

  $sql1="SELECT *
  FROM Material
  WHERE
    ID_Clasificacion LIKE '%".$ID_Clasificacion."%' AND
    ID_Taller LIKE '%".$ID_Taller."%' AND
    ID_Familia LIKE '%".$ID_Familia."%' AND
     Estado LIKE '%".$Estado."%'
  ORDER BY ID_Taller";

  $query1=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1);
?>
```

Comment: Sobreescribes la variable $ID en ese otro archivo?

Comment: @Cris223511.dev ya el código

Comment: @Pipe no lo sobreescribo

Comment: En un archivo lo lees de get, y en otro de post... Por qué?

Comment: @Jakala el archivo que obtiene el get es el principal y el que obtiene por post es el archivo que esta en el include del archivo get

Comment: Haz un esquema o explica mejor el problema, es mas no tiene porque ser tan complejo, un archivo con una variable y dinos como es que quieres que se comporte, pero no como lo has dicho ya, algo más claro, porque en tu segundo archivo no veo como lo mandas al primero...

Comment: @OCHOA tengo un archivo que obtiene una variable por url llamada ID, pero este archivo tiene un include que añade otro archivo, al ejecutar ese archivo y volver al archivo del ID este valor se borra

Comment: `<form action="material_list.php?lavariableporget=elvalorporget" method="post">`

Comment: @aloMalbarez si funciono eso, gracias